# react-redux not dispatching thunk api call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm taking a working web version with redux and Api calls and porting them to a React Native app. However I notice when trying to dispatch a thunk to make an API call, I can't seem to see a console log in my thunk to confirm the dispatch. This makes me think something is not connected properly but I just don't see what that is. What am I missing?

I create a store with an initial state: When I log `store.getState()` everything looks fine.

```js
const initialState = {
  config: fromJS({
    apiUrl: "http://localhost:3000/account-data",
  })
}
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
  )
)
```

I use mapDispatchToProps and I see the functions in my list of props

```js
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loadProducts: () => dispatch(loadProducts())
  };
}
```

However, when I inspect my `loadProducts` function, I do not see a console log confirming the dispatch.  What's going on here? Why is loadProducts not dispatching?  On the web version I'm able to confirm a network request and logs. On React Native I do not see a network request or these console logs.

```js
export function loadProductsCall() {
  console.log('in RN loadProductsCall') //don't see this
  const opts = constructAxpOpts();
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      types: [
        LOAD_REQUEST,
        LOAD_SUCCESS,
        LOAD_FAILURE
      ],
      callAPI: (client, state) =>
        client.get(`${state.config.get('apiUrl')}/members`, opts),
      shouldForceFetch: () => false,
      isLoaded: state => !!(state.core.resources.products.get('productsOrder') &&
        state.core.resources.products.get('productsOrder').length),
      getResourceFromState: (state) => state.core.resources.products.toJS(),
      isLoading: state => !!state.core.resources.products.get('isLoading'),
      getLoadingPromise: state => state.core.resources.products.get('loadingPromise'),
      payload: {}
    }
  };
}

export function loadProducts() {
  console.log('in loadProducts') //don't see this
  return (dispatch) =>
  console.log('in loadProducts dispatched 2') //don't see this either 
    dispatch(loadProductsCall())
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is missing custom API middleware that handles three action types. Also, in `mapDispatchToProps` a function is wrapping the dispatch. This function need to either be unwrapped and return a promise or called somewhere else in the code.